# Generating a very large array of objects freezes program

Tags: opengl, lwjgl

when I generate a huge array of 13k+ tiles that I want to render as textures onto the screen it crashes and I have no idea why, this is the method that is causing the issue

```
public ArrayList<Tile> getNewChunk(int width, int height)
{
    int amountOfTilesY = height * 32;
    int amountOfTilesX = width * 32;
    int amountOfTiles = (amountOfTilesX + amountOfTilesY) / 32;
    ArrayList<Tile> tiles = new ArrayList<Tile>(amountOfTiles);
    for(int i = 0; i < amountOfTilesX; i += 32)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < amountOfTilesY; j += 32)
        {
            Tile tempTile = new DirtTile(i, j, "res/tile/DirtTile.png");
            tiles.add(tempTile);
        }
    }

    return tiles;

}
```

So if ou could please help :D
the engine I am using to render the game with is lwjgl 2, using opengl
I can provide more code if needed

Comment: You might want to load the DirtTile texture only once and reuse it, because at the moment it seems like you load it separately for each tile. Loading 13,000 textures probably takes a lot of performance and memory.

Comment: On which line is it crashing? On what amount of tiles does it start to crash? How large are the tiles, and what format are they?

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you provided, the issue could come from multiple things. @javec is correct in that loading the texture once per object would drastically reduce performance. You should be loading the single unit and distributing its single unit ID throughout the list.

Also, it is unclear based on what you provided whether or not you are generating buffers for each tile separately here. If so, you should be generating a single buffer and sharing it in the same way.

Depending on what you plan on using these tiles for, you may consider a different method. If the tiles are connected as a terrain, you can always scale your mesh appropriately and tile your texture using something like

```
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT);
```